# с++ PictureBox. Graphics. Стереть нарисованное

Tags: c++, .net, graphics

Есть pictureBox, а на нём ещё и Image.

```
Graphics ^graf;

graf = pictureBox->CreateGraphics();
```

рисую на graf :

```
graf1->DrawLine(Pens::Blue, e->X, e->Y, 0, 0);
```

**как удалить нарисованное?**

```
graf1->Clear..
```

не подходит, т.к. он заливает всё своё пространство цветом, а у меня на **PictureBox** имеется **Image**, которое должно быть видно.

Может можно залить с помощью graf1->Clear.. прозрачным цветом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно говоря, не совсем понял, что вам нужно. Но залить прозрачным цветом можно, для этого применяется `Color.Transparent`.

```
graf.Clear(Color.Transparent);
```

Это код на C#. У вас аналогично на C++.
Кроме того, следует знать, что у picturebox есть свойства BackgroundImage и Image. Благодаря им можно как быть накладывать изображения друг на друга. Чтобы их использовать, рисуйте сначала на Bitmap, а потом применяйте его к этим свойствам

Comment: graf->Clear(Color::Transparent); заливал почему-то чёрным. 

Переделал всё так, чтобы можно было на Bitmap рисовать и присваивать его Image.
Спасибо

Comment: @usk-dima пожалуйста. Я  вообще  `Color.Transparent` применял к Bitmap (чтоб накладывать друг на друга). Это как бы дословно "цвет родителя" , Bitmap по умолчанию и так заливается этим цветом при создании. У формы же родителя как бы нет, может поэтому цвет по умолчанию черный.